# I my app i want to show some test as url link as watspp is showing when we type or copy paste a url

Tags: java, android

In my mobile app want to show url as link as if you type a url in whatsapp it shows as link, similary i want to show the url in link so how to identify that given test is a url or normal test??

Answer (score 0):

Try [this Android example](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview) Link Preview library on github

just add the repository to your build.gradle file

```
repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy'}
     }
```

and dependencies  are

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3' // required
compile 'com.leocardz:link-preview:1.2.1@aar'

}
```

Hope it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your Strings.xml file declare one string as :

```
   <string name="ji"><a href="">Forgot Password?</a></string>
```

on your activity_layout

```
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/messageWithLinkTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/ji"

         />
```

In your activity.java class

```
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageWithLinkTextView);
}
```

try this